# How to find my Gmail SMTP Server

Tags: gmail, smtp

I want to activate Blat, but I don't know my SMTP Server which is needed. Is there a way using the command line, or in Gmail itself to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmails SMTP Server address is: smtp.gmail.com

You can login with your email address and password.

More info at: [G Suite Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).